# Select sequence of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table like

```
ID | Type
---------
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 2
4  | 2
5  | 1
6  | 2
7  | 2
```

I need a SQL way to select rows of Type 2 between rows of Type 1, passing the ID of a row

Example:

```
Selecting rows after ID 1

Wanted result:
ID | Type
---------
2  | 2
3  | 2
4  | 2

Selecting rows after ID 5

Wanted result:
ID | Type
---------
6  | 2
7  | 2
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not sure if this can apply as a gaps and islands problem.

Comment: You are right @LuisCazares. I just tossed this on the pile without much thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible option.

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData(
    ID int, 
    Type int);
INSERT INTO SampleData
VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 2),
(4, 2),
(5, 1),
(6, 2),
(7, 2);
DECLARE @ID int =1;--Parameter

DECLARE @NextID int = (SELECT TOP 1 ID 
                       FROM SampleData 
                       WHERE ID > @ID 
                       AND Type = 1 
                       ORDER BY ID);

SELECT *
FROM SampleData
WHERE Type = 2
AND ID > @ID
AND (ID < @NextID OR @NextID IS NULL);
```

This would be an example on how to create an inline table-valued function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetSubset(
    @ID int 
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
    SELECT *
    FROM SampleData sd
    WHERE sd.Type = 2
    AND sd.ID > @ID
    AND sd.ID <= ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 i.ID 
                       FROM SampleData i
                       WHERE i.ID > @ID 
                       AND i.Type = 1 
                       ORDER BY i.ID), sd.ID);
```

Comment: I created a function that use the SQL that you post and used it.
Thank you a lot

Comment: Be aware that multi-statement table-valued functions can be over 40 times slower than the regular code or an inline table-valued function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id > 5 and
      t.type = 2 and
      t.id < coalesce( (select min(t2.id)
                        from t t2
                        where t2.id > 5 and
                              t2.type = 1
                       ), 999999999
                     );
```

Or more elegantly as:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id > 5 and
      t.type = 2 and
      t.id < all (select t2.id
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id > 5 and
                        t2.type = 1
                 );
```